# PHP regex - find and replace

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to do this regex match and replace but not able to do it.

Example

```
<SPAN class="one">first content here</SPAN>
<SPAN class="two">second content here </SPAN>
<SPAN class="three">one; two; three; and more.</span>
<SPAN class="four">more content here.</span>
```

I want to find each set of the span tags and replace with something like this

**Find**

`<SPAN class="one">first content here</SPAN>`

**Change to**

`<one>first content here</one>`

same way the the rest of the span tags.

`class="one"`, `class="two"` and so on are the only key identifier which I use in the regex match expression. So if I find a span tag with these class then I want to do the replace. My main issue is that I am not able to find the occurrence of first closing tag so what it does is it finds from the start to end which is of no use. So far I have been trying to do this using notepad++ but just found that it has its limitations so any php help would be appreciated.

regards

Comment: Hi,

I forgot to put code tag so the q is messed up. please read it below in the reply post.

Comment: You know you can edit your post if you see a mistake, you don't need to post the fix as an answer.

Comment: I am sorry, I tried to look for that option but couldnt find it. Please let me know and I can delete the answer post and correct the question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/<span class="(.*?)">(.*?)<\/span>/i', '<$1>$2</$1>', $input);
```

Comment: but there is a typo. should add a ) before the double quotes ends.